# Не( )применимо - слитно/раздельно

Tags: орфография

> Ты спрашиваешь почему? Потому что к нам это слово не( )применимо же!

Слитно/раздельно писать это слово с "не" в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Ты спрашиваешь почему? Потому что к нам это слово неприменимо же!***

В данном случае желательно слитное написание НЕ, хотя раздельное форма тоже возможна.

**Пояснение**

1. Существует пара прилагательных: *применимый – неприменимый*.

**НЕПРИМЕНИМЫЙ,**  такой, что нельзя применить, использовать; непригодный. Н. совет. Н. план. Н-ая теория.

Эти слова могут быть только прилагательными, так как образованы от глагола **совершенного** вида «применить». (Действительные причастия настоящего времени с суффиксами ИМ/ЕМ образуются от глаголов несовершенного вида: применять – применяемый.)

2. В Нацкорпусе слитное написание встречается чаще (105:37).

По счастью, это правило **неприменимо** к информационной гражданской войне. [И. Ю. Алексеева., 2015]

Однако к современным конкурсным отношениям **никак не применимо** другое высказывание Г. Ф. Шершеневича…  [2003.09.29]

И слово «травма» к ним **не применимо**. [Марина Зосимкина. (2015)]

3. Прилагательное «неприменимый» подчиняется **общим правилам** для прилагательных: зависимые слова не влияют на написание НЕ; полная и краткая формы пишутся одинаково; существуют слова, усиливающие отрицание (никак не, никогда не) или утверждение (весьма, крайне, очень, почти).
4. **Особое правило** существует для прилагательных, которые употребляются с зависимыми словами, **дополняющими смысловое значение** исходного глагола (применить что-то к чему-либо).

Здесь раздельное написание частицы НЕ рекомендуется при постановке прилагательного с зависимыми словами **после определяемого существительного**, ср.: *Шахматист играл в несвойственном ему стиле.* — *Это черты, **не свойственные** нашей молодёжи.*  (Розенталь. [Частица ***не*** с прилагательными](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77), пункт 8).

Comment: Может, стоит изменить как-то это предложение: *К причастиям эти слова не относятся, так как образованы от глагола совершенного вида «применить»*? А то получается, что от глаголов СВ причастия не образуются.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде исправила.

Comment: По интернету ходит вот такая байка: https://vk.com/wall-40180261_527653 не знаю, насколько правда)

Comment: @Nektoid
 Да, забавная шутка, я тоже слышала. Как говорится, даже если не сказал, то мог бы и должен был сказать. На этом примере очень наглядно объясняется разница между наличием падежного управления (раздельное написание ПО) и его отсутствием (слитное написание).